# Insert template instncaes on clicking event meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm a newbie to Meteor. I want to insert a new table every time when I click on the button. I implemented the table in a template but I'm not sure how to insert an instance of the template every time clicking on the button.

html

```
<template name="addTable">
  <button type="button" id="addTables" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
</template>
```

js

```
Template.addTable.events({
   'click #addTables': function(e){
       var button = $(e.currentTarget);
       button.before(//I want to add code here to insert one instance of template Table here)
    }
})
```

The effect I want is after clicking on the button once, one `{{> Table}}` can be inserted before `<button type="button" id="addTables" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">` in html. Anyone has idea how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ready to use code, just adjust the table and row styling as per your requirement.

```js
Template.table.events({
 'click #addRow'(e,t){
  let table = t.find('.table');;
  Blaze.render(Template.row,table);
 }
})
```

```html
<body>
  {{> table}}
</body>
<template name="table">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="myRow">
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr><br>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button class="btn btn-warning pull-right" id="addRow">Add Row</button>
</template>
<template name="row">
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>
</template>
```

here we are making use of Blaze.render which takes the row you want to render next and table as the parent table.

you can assign the table using t.find() which finds for the class inside template.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. But I'm still a bit confused about how to exactly insert one more instance of the template (here is actually a table) in the code.